# What lubricant should I use for an outside garage door lock?

Tags: exterior, lubrication, locks

I recently asked [what sort of lubricant I should use on locks](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/what-kind-of-lubrication-should-i-use-for-a-lock).

I was wondering if the advice there (i.e. graphite powder) applied to an outside garage door handle lock?

The lock in question looks like this, and is outside, unsheltered.

[image: Garage door handle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use a dry silicone lubricant like [this](http://www.toolboxsupply.com/productdetails.aspx?sku=10834525).

[image]

Or a graphite lubricant like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BXKYUW).

[image]

The liquid part of these lubricants evaporates quickly, leaving behind a protective coating that will keep the lock functioning properly for quite some time.

You don't want to use a lubricant like [WD-40](http://www.wd40.com/), because it will not evaporate completely and will collect dirt and debris and eventually freeze the lock again.

For an exterior lock exposed to the elements, you'll want to reapply the lubricant occasionally (about once every year or two depending on the weather), or anytime the lock seems sticky.

Comment: Excellent, cheers for the details and especially the pictures.