# How do I remove a Kwikset deadbolt with no screws on the inside plate?

Tags: locks, deadbolt

My exterior door deadbolt has gotten stuck - it'll open with the lever but not the key. By spraying WD-40 inside the lock, I've been able to get it to work but it's very stiff. I'd like to remove the lock and inspect the inside, either to clean/lube it or replace it. But I can't figure out how to remove the lock; there's no obvious way to do this. (I'm used to seeing two screws on the inside of the deadbolt, usually under the lever arms when it's horizontal.)

[image][image]

How do I remove this? I can loosen the cover plate on the inside but it doesn't do anything other than rotate a few degrees.

Comment: FIY: WD-40 should not be used to [lubricate locks](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/6695/33)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First thing you need to do is find the set screw that releases the inside handle. then you pry off the escutcheon plate (trim plate). the two screws you are looking for are under the trim plate.

[image]

Comment: Some Kwikset models use a small plastic pin to retain the knob.It is removed with a pair of needle nose pliers.

Comment: Yep. sometimes a small metal push pin on the knob.

Comment: Removing the set screw requires a tiny 1/16th allen wrench

Comment: It's actually a 1/20 or .05 Allen wrench. Good post though. It let me get my lock replaced

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find a replacement set screw for this? (I have the same model and the screw came loose and disappeared somewhere)