# Key stuck halfway in door lock

Tags: lock

My bedroom door has a lock on it and the key is stuck between a 90 degree turn and the top (pictures below). The weird thing is that when I turn it counter clockwise it moves the latch bolt just a tiny amount and then gets stuck again. I’ve tried turning the handle while attempting to unlock or remove the key and everything else I could think of. I really don’t want to have to call my landlord just for a locksmith to come and fix it in 10 seconds because of something stupid I couldn’t think of. I’ve never seen a key/lock get stuck like this before so all help is appreciated, thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would try squirting a little bit of WD-40 in the keyway to try to loosen it.  Any kind of light oil will do.

Comment: A product called Houdini is meant specifically for lubricating locks. Spray it in liberally though the delivery tube that comes with the can

Comment: Quickly check the keys, check if key is the correct one.

Comment: What a bummer! Can you disassemble the lock assembly and remove it. If so you could then take it to a locksmith if you cannot get the key out.

Comment: The landlord is responsible for the locks on the doors, and there's no evidence that you've done anything wrong or unusual here, so call your landlord. Either it's defective or someone else has put something in the keyway that's jammed it.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try the suggestions to lubricate the lock. I cannot remove the key either so I assume I must spray through the other side of the lock opening.

Comment: Squirt the lube directly into the lock where the key enters. Even with the key in the way, some of it will work its way past the key itself and into the cylinder. If there's a hole in the other side of the knob, you probably won't get lube into the actual cylinder itself, just inside the knob and general mechanism area. Of course, if the latch is stuck instead of the key/cylinder, that may be exactly what you need!

Comment: If it's a Euro, they're 'straight through' so you can squirt from the other side.

Answer (score 2):

That looks pretty much like a standard Euro Cylinder.
On the face plate on the edge of the door, about the height of the cylinder, there should be a cross-head [Phillips] screw. Release that & by jiggling the key in the lock you should be able to pull the barrel towards you & clear of the door.

That will at least let you get a slightly better look at it. They're a bit monolithic, so there's not a lot you can do with them if some oil & a poke doesn't do it. They're not worth trying to split. If you do need to replace it, you can get new ones for as little as $£€ 10 [more for higher security].

While you've got the barrel out, you may as well have a look at the actual lock mechanism & make sure you can move it easily. You might get better access with the entire plate off the door edge… but you might not. Some are easier to deal with than others & you won't know til you start to open it up.
Getting to all this is pretty simple stuff. It's only once you get to the innards you face issues. Mostly locks aren't 'user serviceable' so don't bother if oil & finagling gains nothing - just replace.

A locksmith will, of course charge you more like 70 to just change the barrel, so it might gain favours with the landlord. Have a word.

Comment: Always good to check with the landlord before making "repairs". Even though you're willing to make the fix yourself & at your own expense, a cranky one might try to claim it's and unapproved modification and withhold security/damage deposit money. (Local laws may vary.)

Comment: Absolutely - this one is one you can 'have a sneaky look at' first, though ;)) if you can't fix it, put it back & ring the landlord. Tell him your genius scheme to save him money. I have a good landlord. If I had something like this I'd just fix it & tell him what it cost me. He'd sort the money.

Comment: A house call for this will be orders of magnitude more expensive than the lock itself. Get the landlord approval for a self-replacement, with ample photos documenting what was done and what the insides of the door like.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a dream. Well not quite haha but after a lot of frustrated fiddling and pushing the cylinder back and forth the key could turn fully around and work as normal from both sides of the lock!

Comment: Uh, you should either replace it, or grease it up (if you know what you're doing, not WD40!) You're just asking to be locked out one day and that'll require a locksmith and $$$$.

Comment: I really don't know what people seem to have against WD49. It's easy to spray in, it penetrates, it lubricates. Once a year or two is all is needs. Lots of people have fallen for the interwebz meme that "It's a water disperser and not a lubricant" which is just fake news. https://www.wd40.com/myths-legends-fun-facts/

Comment: @Tetsujin https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/6696/32689 WD-40 is good for temporary work, but is not a long-term solution. Why in the world would you want to lubricate a lock once a year? A properly lubricated lock will stay lubricated for decades.