# How do I stop a bed frame from squeaking?

Tags: furniture, bedroom

I recently bought a second hand wooden bed frame. All is good except it squeaks quite a lot when I move around on it (ahem). Any advice on fixing the annoying squeak?

**EDIT** :: photo of the joint

[image: photo]

Comment: Is there a lot of movement involved (in the frame)? how are the joints attached (bolts, screws, nails)?

Comment: If i push it then it does have some give. Joints are attached by a piece of metal with three slots that slot into the sides.

Comment: A picture of the joints may help.

Comment: Yeh, I probably explained it badly. Ill try and post one this evening.

Comment: @Tester101 See the edit

Comment: (ahem) "move around" on the couch, or in the kitchen, or the shower, or ... ;)

Comment: bar soap rub on joints

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed my metal bedframe by putting leather patches between parts that are rubbing.
Wooden frame is a bit more tricky - not so easy to identify where the parts are rubbing, but this is the first initial step. 
I'd say check all the joints and see if you can tighten the bolts or add glue to moving parts.

Basically, the noise comes from parts rubbing on each other. If you can eliminate rubbing, or put something between the rubbing parts - that would reduce the noise.

Comment: Glue the joints with PVA possibly?

Comment: Don't think that PVA will work as permanent solution, but will help to identify the issue

Comment: You can take some felt or other thick material and cut slots in it for the metal parts to go through.  This will both help reduce the wood on wood noise, and tighten up the joints a bit.

Comment: Guys you should wax the joint then screw them back together!!

Answer (score 5):

Most times with anything wood, it is not the wood rubbing together that is squeaking, it is your nails, screws, bolts, or whatever holding it together that are loose rubbing on the wood that squeak.  I would go around your bed frame and tighten everything.  If you find one that wont tighten you can use some wood glue in the hole to help with the squeaks(If you dont plan on taking it apart in the future :))

Answer (score 2):

Does the bed have slats?

I was ready to throw away a daybed for being incredibly noisy, but before I did, I replaced the fancy springy laminated-wood slats it used to have with cheap plain wooden slats. The squeaks stopped immediately. Turns out, the fancy slats were just a tad bit too big, and the ends were rubbing against the frame at the slightest provocation, producing the noise.

I'm still using the fancy slats in a different bed, where they work perfectly. The point is, neither the bed nor the slats were at fault; the problem was with the combination.

Comment: Yes, I am using slats

Comment: @Tom: does the frame squeak when the slats are not in place? I'm guessing most of the noise is coming from the slats rubbing (this would be especially prevalent during curtain um... "noise making" motions). You could try coating the ends of the slats with something that will reduce friction (baby powder, silicone spray), or try securing the slats to the rail (so they can't move).  Also check the box spring, cheaply made box springs can be very noisy.

Answer (score 2):

We just solved the problem of creaky slats.  We cut up strips of those cheap egg crate bed toppers and wrapped it anywhere the wood slats meet the bed frame.  No more creaking during fun time!

Comment: You just wrapped the frame in the foam material?

Answer (score 2):

Beeswax or paraffin. Your local hardware store probably will have both as they're used for lubricating drawer slides on older joinery.

Knock the joint apart apply to where the wood rubs. Lift the slats out and apply it there as well.

Beeswax is slightly sticky and will adhere to metal, so it will probably work on the hooks on the metal joint as well.

Tighten anything that's loose on the headboard and side rails afterwards and it should all go away.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I lift wooden floorboards, I sprinkle simple talcum (baby) powder where the boards sit. Ditto, although rather more difficult to get at the squeaky areas, wooden stairs.
Obviously it depends on whether you can access the point where wood meets wood - but that is the area to be "lubricated".
Unfortunately, soft woods tend to wear and then you need to start again.

Answer (score 0):

Spray some WD40 on the metal parts (screws) just did this and it works a treat!

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/when-should-i-not-use-wd-40