# What is causing the SUPER loud noise from my dryer

Tags: repair, dryer

I have a maytag gas dryer. It is about 20 years old. Model number DG7500

It sounds like an jet engine taking off. I've noticed that it starts off quiet than builds up to a very lour roar.

I googled -> rollers are bad. Bought new rollers, bearings,idle wheel,etc (150 CAD can be returned if unopened).

Pull off the access panels, look at idle wheel and roller, they don't look much different than the new ones.

So, I put in some wet laundry, ran it to see if I could spot the cause of the noise (of course, if it is resonant noise this probably wouldn't work). It didn't really get super loud this time. All the rollers and the idle wheel spun.

So, before I open the packages and take everything apart I'd like to get your thoughts on whether or not this is the problem. Any ideas?

Photos of current rollers & idle wheel:

[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>Click for larger view</sup>

UPDATE 1:

- WD40'd the roller: no real change
- fluff for 10 mins, loud but I think it is normal for this one
- DRY for 10 mins: 3-4 minutes in gets super loud again. So heat is probably playing a factor in this
- Describe the noise: not a whine. Very loud rumble.

UPDATE 2: 
- After buying all the parts suggested (Roller x2, gliderx2, idle wheel and belt) I took the cover, bulkhead, and drum all off. The problem was a dryer sheet caught in the blower. Removed, cleaned and replaced the belt (old one was pretty close to its last days) and it's all good now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for inlining @Tester101 didn't know SE supports that :) Will update my other question....

Comment: If you run the dryer in fluff(no heat cycle) is the noise still present? I am curious about whether the noise is from the flame bar or a mechanical noise.

Comment: when I did the fluff with dry clothes in it, it didn't make the noise but it seems to do after a length of time, not just right away, like when it's cold not noisy, warm super loud.

Comment: Did you let it run long enough with dry clothes that it would have made the noise?

Comment: No, i didn't think it was helpful at the time. But i'll do that again tonight.

Comment: Belt is probably slipping. The warmer it gets, the looser and louder it gets.

Comment: Would you describe the noise as high pitch whine or lower frequency rumble?

Comment: mikes: updated the question: not whine, loud rumble @bcworkz yeah i think so too after the heat/fluff test.

Comment: I'm not so sure about it being the belt if it's a rumbling noise. Let's see what happens after you lube the rollers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say without actually standing in front of it and observing the noise, but I'm going to guess you have some shot bearings somewhere. It's easier to point to them in an image to suggest where they may be descriptively:

[image: shot-bearings]

To the left you have casters to keep the dryer on course. Applying some Teflon (or silicone) may cure it. To the right, the motor - and the sound you're hearing may mean that it is dying. That's not something you can really service beyond replacing it.

It could also simply be the belt that's attached to the motor. The same 'belt dressing' that you can buy in an auto parts store to cure a fan noise in your car will likely show (or eliminate) the belt as the culprit. It is probably quite old if it hasn't been replaced since being purchased. The inside of a dryer can get quite humid, so those belts can last for a really long time.

So check lube or 'dress' anything that helps the dryer spin, *except* the motor, first. If that fails, then look into getting a replacement motor (or new dryer, possibly). Rule out anything that has steel bearings first, and the belt.

Comment: Okay, let's assume/hope its not the motor. Can I replace the bearing and re-use the old wheels or replace the it all?

Comment: Oh, and there is any way to check the health of the motor?

Comment: A little lubrication might just fix them (the bearings), if that's the case (WD-40)

Comment: As for the motor, not easily, you'd have to disconnect the pulley and then energize it to hear it spin, and it may be making that noise only under load. It's probably better to eliminate all _but_ the motor first.

Comment: No WD40! http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/when-should-i-not-use-wd-40

Comment: @Steven What would you recommend, then?

Comment: Ideally the same substance that was already used - silicone, white lithium, Teflon, graphite, etc.

Comment: okay i will try that. I have teflon for my bike. THanks Steven, i did put some on but not a lot.

Comment: @Steven Thanks :) Edited. I had no idea that stuff could actually make things worse.