# How to lubricate door lock?

Tags: lock, lubrication

My door lock needs care, the key is hard to put in.

I've got this in my previous apartment and I got some 'magic cream' from a friend which worked like a charm, but unfortunately, I don't have this anymore and I haven't noted what was this.

What kind of lubricant works fine for door locks? I don't want to get it stuck more.

Comment: Graphite power usually works well, does not drip like oils.  If key is hard to put in, instead of turning, might be damage to the lock or key.

Comment: silicone spray applied to the key works well

Comment: I use WD-40 or a similar product. You don't need much. Just spray a little on the key and insert it into the lock, and turn it repeatedly.

Comment: Oil holds onto dust, causing future problems. A drop on the key itself might not be too bad, but *not* in the lock. As @crip659 states, use graphite or powdered PTFE.

Comment: Stay with dry material like graphite or moly sulfide .

Answer (score -1):

In addition to graphite powder, other lubricants for door lock mechanisms include silicone lube, grease lubrication, and Teflon-based lube. A penetrating liquid like WD-40 or white lithium grease is another option. Consider the local weather conditions before selecting a suitable lubricant.

Comment: I wouldn't put any grease or oil in a door lock mechanism. It'll just make a mess, including on the key, which you then put in your pocket or purse. Also, [how many questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/115243/clean-and-lubricate-garage-door-rails) are you going to copy/paste this answer to?